# Why does rowspan "3" delete one entire row and sets it to "2"

Tags: html, html-table

I need help with `rowspan`, I set it to 3 and `colspan` to 3, but it deletes one entire row and sets it to 2.
I have 4 rows in my table but when I write the code it ends up to 3 rows. I don't understand why doesn't it span properly, thanks for the answer, here is the HTML code below.

```css
td {
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; table-layout: fixed; border: 2px solid black;" align="center" width="50%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="4">7</td>
    <td rowspan="2" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">8</td>
    <td rowspan="3" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't get why., but you can write any number above `3` as `rowspan` for `<td rowspan="3" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>`. It will alwys look the same on Chrome

Answer (score 0):

That's really strange behaviour, but the reason obviously is that *none* of your columns actually contains four cells (three is the most) and all cells only have very little content (if at all), so the table is being reduced/compressed to three rows in height.

I would definitely call that a rendering or interpretation error of the browser. But...

The crucial point seems to be the second cell in the first row, which should be two rows high: If you actually put some more content into it, it *will* be two rows high, and the whole table will be displayed as desired. See my snippet below, where the only real difference to your code is the additional content in the second `td`:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table align="center" width="50%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="4">A1</td>
    <td rowspan="2" colspan="2">A2 containing more text</td>
    <td>A3</td>
    <td colspan="3">A4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">B1</td>
    <td rowspan="3" colspan="3">B2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C1</td>
    <td>C2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>D1</td>
    <td>D2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

P.S.: Note also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64628133/5641669) answer of mine to a very similar question.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get it with the table, but `display: grid;` exists now.
Here is the template with this solution :

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "a b b g i i i"
    "a b b h j j j"
    "a c d h j j j"
    "a e f h j j j";
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.grid-container > div {
    border: 1px solid;
}
.a { grid-area: a; }
.b { grid-area: b; }
.c { grid-area: c; }
.d { grid-area: d; }
.e { grid-area: e; }
.f { grid-area: f; }
.g { grid-area: g; }
.h { grid-area: h; }
.i { grid-area: i; }
.j { grid-area: j; }
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="b">b</div>
  <div class="c">c</div>
  <div class="d">d</div>
  <div class="e">e</div>
  <div class="f">f</div>
  <div class="g">g</div>
  <div class="h">h</div>
  <div class="i">i</div>
  <div class="j">j</div>
</div>
```