# Impossible HTML table to do

Tags: html, css, html-table

I need to do the following table in HTML, too easy:

[image: Result]

The problem is in the second row, the second column only has one row, not two, in the code is `rowspan = "2"`. Why doesn't work my code, is simple to do, I don't understand this problem, really…

[image: Wrong result]

The following is the relevant code:

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>X</td>
    <td rowspan="2" colspan="3">X</td>
    <td rowspan="3">X</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">X</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: My rowspan is correctly, the second row, the second column must be 2 row, in the result is only one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just answered a  very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64582095/5641669) a few days ago. Apparently, if *none* of the columns contains the full amount of intended rows and the cell contents allow it, browsers "compress" the content into less rows (which IMO is a bug or at least, a misinterpretation, but well...).

As soon as you add more content into your cells (at least in those that *do*  make a difference), the desired layout is rendered, with height according to the cell contents:

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>X</td>
    <td rowspan="2" colspan="3">some more content in here some more content in here some more content in here some more content in here some more content in here some more content in here some more content in here some more content in here some more content in here some more content in here some more content in here some more content in here some more content in here some more content in here some more content in here some more content in here some more content in here</td>
    <td rowspan="3">X</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">X</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But alternatively, you can add a fixed height to one or some of the cells to make the intended layout visible, even if they don't have as much content:

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>X</td>
    <td rowspan="2" colspan="3" style="height: 80px;">X</td>
    <td rowspan="3">X</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">X</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I just experimented a little and you're right! It works fine if I either add a column of single cells or when I put longer content to it. I thought it was a broken design, but it looks more like a problem with calculating height. With short content, that biggest cell is still a tiny bit taller than its row. Great find, @Johannes!

Comment: Thanks Johannes, I will use height property to fix this